# PHP Curl - headers not persisting across redirect

Tags: php, redirect, curl, oauth

I am writing a webservice client which runs from the command line and accesses a service which uses Oauth2.

I seem to be getting the Oauth token correctly, and the first request to the webservice recognizes the token. However the response is a 303 redirect (I have set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` => true) however the subsequent page says that I have supplied no authentication token.

Currently I am passing the oauth token by setting a header for the curl handle:

```
"Authorization: OAuth2 $oauth"
```

I suspect that the header is not being included in subsequent requests.

I tried setting  `CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH` => true, to no avail (but according to the manual, that persists a username and password across redirects - not the authentication header).

The webservice allows for oauth tokens to be sent in an authentication header or in the URL (but not as a cookie). Setting the token in the URL returns the same redirect (i.e. without the token in the URL) hence I can't use this method with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`.

(the service does not allow for oauth tokens sent in cookies, PHP version is 5.6)

Comment: you are requesting to a SSL host?

Comment: Yes (which makes it rather difficult to see what the code is actually doing)

Comment: have you added: curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); on curl options?

Comment: That's predicated on the idea my client cannot verify the host certificate (it can't and I already have those options in place). While I appreciate your intentions here, it's going to take some time for you to guess the 200 or so lines of code that I currently use to get an oath token - which is too much to publish here. I created a test rig and identified a bug elsewhere in the code which was resetting the header - this was not initially evident due to an overzealous caching proxy which was not handling the 'Vary' header correctly.

Comment: hi, add curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); and print the output of curl_exec to see the result of your cURL request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having discovered that lots of other bad things are happening on the Websense proxy I was connecting via (caching content known to be expired, caching POST responses!) I tried bypassing it altogether and all the problems vanished.